# Format number in typescript map

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new in typescript and my question is how to format data in map? 
Output is map of numbers like 24150, 12012, 36012, 300124 and I want to show it like 24 150, 12 012, 36 012, 300 124. I need to separate thousand.

```
 let koopMap = coefsCopy.map(innerMap =>
    innerMap.map(value => value * area)
  );
```

Comment: I believe you can cast each number to string and inject a space in required position. Well, it's better to create a Pipe for this if it's about angular.

Comment: For angular create a Pipe to format how a value is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to transform `24150` to  `24 150`. Assuming the original is a `number` you would:

```
let foo = 24150;
let bar =  foo.toString().substring(0, foo.toString().length - 3) + ' ' + foo.toString().substr(-3); // '24 150'
```

For mapping in an array use `map` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map